# startActivity not working in Android Method

Tags: java, android, android-intent, start-activity

I'm currently writing an android app that involves an Activity that creates a canvas and a thread to modify the canvas, and I'm trying to create a button in the options bar to return to the menu. The menu definitely works (as you must pass through it to start the current activity), and the Activity, Canvas, and Thread work (as once you start them they function correctly as far as I can tell), but in the method for returning to the menu Android will not complete the startActivity method following an intent to return to the menu class. This is after I stop the thread and declare the intent, as upon several iterations of different ideas sometimes log cat throws an error at the startActivity line. Usually, however, I do not get an error, instead I get a switch to a blank black screen that can not be interfaced with, after the animation stops (which as far as  can tell is the thread shutting down). My code is as follows:

```
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menureturn:
            super.onDestroy();
        try {
            panel.getThread().setRunning(false);
            panel.getThread().join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent menu = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuSplash.class);
        menu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(menu);

            return true;
```

Any help you can give me would be fantastic!

Comment: Why do you call .join()? This thread can't handle it self? I don't know whole background, but it looks like that this is the reason of black screen...

Answer (score 0):

Is this code running on UI thread, if not try make an intent on UI thread like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        // This runs on the UI thread
        Intent menu = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuSplash.class);
        menu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(menu);
    }
});
```